# Mongoose update over iterator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to iterate over a stream and update records if they are already in mongo or create them otherwise:

```
School.findOne({nces_schid: mergeSchool['nces_schid']})
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, school){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if(school) {
            delete mergeSchool['nces_schid'];
            School.update({nces_schid: school['nces_schid']}, {$set: mergeSchool}, {multi: true})
            .lean()
            .exec(function (err, updatedSchool) {
                console.log(err);
                mongoCallback(updatedSchool, err, education);
        });
        }
        else {
            School.create(mergeSchool, function (err, newSchool) {
                mongoCallback(newSchool, err, education);
      });
        }
    });
```

When this actually runs the stream loads all of the data in very fast, but the updates happen at an extremely slow rate.  Around 1 per 3 seconds, with a lot of data this takes too much time.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

use {upsert:true} and there will be no need of if else conditions see documentation about upsert:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

your code will be like this:

```
School.findOneAndUpdate({nces_schid: mergeSchool['nces_schid']},mergeSchool,{upsert:true})
    .exec(function(err, school){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(school)
    });
```

Comment: This still seems to be extremely slow, is there anyway this can be done using a bulk operation?